# WooCommerce Auto Complete not working for shipping details form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, woocommerce

WooCommerce Auto Complete not working for shipping details form, Tried some jQuery codes like below, but nothing helped me, can someone give some advice?

**jQuery**

```
function enableAutocomplete() {
  $(‘:input, form’).attr( ‘autocomplete’, ‘on’ );
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" placeholder="Street address" autocomplete="address-line1" value="">
```

Comment: Improve syntax highlighting and re-indent code for readability

Comment: try $('form input').attr(...)